# MySQL ERROR 13 (HY000) on database creation

Tags: permissions, mysql, 15.04

The full error is:

```
MySQL ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './databasename' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

I can't create databases in the mysql shell. I can log in as root just fine and I've granted all privileges to the root user, flushed privileges and exited/logged back in multiple times. Nothing seems to work.

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04. This worked fine on 14.04, but I'd rather not downgrade if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong permissions, the server runs as `mysql`. Correct with:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/databasename
```

example:

```
% top -u mysql
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                             
15891 mysql     20   0    4472   1684   1536 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 mysqld_safe                                                                                                                                                         
16240 mysql     20   0  728684 117020  12068 S   0,0  2,9   0:00.38 mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's all about permission.

But in my macbook 2017, i should set mysql permission to specific data folder like

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

And now it's works